# Typescript - object is possibly null

Tags: typescript

I am creating simple function to count all existing vowels in given string. I wrote function to do it but I cannot compile this with Typescript version higher than 3. I am curious how this function should be written to pass Typescript versions higher than 3.

```
function getCount(str: string = ''): number {
      return str.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;
    }
```

test:

```
describe("getCount", function(){
    it ("should pass a sample test", function(){
        assert.strictEqual(getCount("abracadabra"), 5)
    });
});
```

With Typescript version 2.4 everything passes but with higher versions I am getting this:

> error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

Comment: It seems strange to give a default value to the `str` , since you're counting the number of vowels in a string, the string should be required? Maybe consider removing the initial value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because .match() will return null if there is no match found.

If it is null then length cannot be used. You could save the outcome of `str.match(/[aeiou]/gi)` to a variable and then check it is not null. The resulting function could look like this:

```
function getCount(str: string = ''): number {
  let matched = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
  if(matched) return matched.length;
  else return 0;
}
```

Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to find more about match.

Comment: Yeah I saw that too, thanks for your answer!